# React useState update without set throught child component

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a logic in my code that i don't understand, i can update a state (useState) throught my child components but without the "set" function.
Here is my (simplified) code :

```
const Main = () =>{
    const [mission, setMission] = useState({activity:"", env:""})
    
    const see = () =>{
        console.log(mission)
    }

    return (
         <Child1 data={mission} />
         <button onClick={see}>TEST</button>
    )
}

const Child1 = (props) =>{
    const {data} = props

    const [mission, setMission] = useState(data)

    const handleChange = (value) =>{
        mission["activity"] = value
    }
  
    return (
         <Child2 data={mission} onChange={handleChange} />
    )
}

const Child2 = (props) =>{
     const {data} = props

     const [activity, setActivity] = useState(data.activity)

     const handleChange = (e) =>{
         setActivity(e.target.value)
         props.onChange(e.target.value)
     }

     return (
          <input value={data} onChange={handleChange} />
     )
}
```

I tried in sandbox and it work too, "mission" did update it's value throught all childs without any "setMission".
I'm relativily new to react so i miss something but i don't know what, can someone explain ?

Thank you

Comment: You're passing an object (by reference) to children, they modify this object. It does not change the state of the `Main` component. If you add something like `<div>{mission.activity}</div>` to `Main` you'll see that it won't update - it won't re-render because the state has not changed.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. So is it ok to do that and use the set when i need to re-render ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to ["lift the state up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Only the `Main` component should `useState`. Then pass both the state value and update function to the child component. The child component will call this update function when it updates. This will update the state on the parent properly and re-render.

Using your example:

```
const Main = () => {
  // Only one state at the top level
  const [mission, setMission] = useState({ activity: "", env: "" });

  const see = () => {
    console.log(mission);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Pass both the value and state update function to the child */}
      <Child1 data={mission} update={setMission} />
      <button onClick={see}>TEST</button>
      <div>{mission.activity}</div>
    </>
  );
};

const Child1 = (props) => {
  const { data, update } = props;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // This will set parent's state
    update({ ...data, activity: e.target.value });
  };

  // You can follow the similar pattern to the next child
  return <Child2 data={data} onChange={handleChange} />;
};
```

You can see a complete working example in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-pond-33rsm?file=/src/Main.js).